# How to use WaitForSingleObject

Tags: c++, windows

In order to try out how to program with the Win32 API, I wrote a program that creates a process.
Then I want to check if my process waits for the newly created process, close the handle and then check WaitForSingleObject again (the second process is sleeping for 700 ms)

First process:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    bool ret;
    bool retwait;

    STARTUPINFO startupinfo;
    GetStartupInfo (&startupinfo);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pro2info;

    wchar_t wcsCommandLine[] = L"D:\\betriebssystemePRA1PRO2.exe";

    ret = CreateProcess(NULL, wcsCommandLine, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL,
                        NULL, &startupinfo, &pro2info);

    cout<<"hProcess: "<<pro2info.hProcess<<endl;
    cout<<"dwProcessId: "<<pro2info.dwProcessId <<endl;

    if (retwait= WaitForSingleObject (pro2info.hProcess, INFINITE)==true)
        cout<<"waitprocess:true"<<endl; //The process is finished
    else
        cout<<"waitprocess:false"<<endl;

    CloseHandle (pro2info.hProcess);//prozesshandle schließen, "verliert connection"

    if (retwait= WaitForSingleObject (pro2info.hProcess, INFINITE)==true) //When the process has finished
        cout<<"waitprocess:true"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"waitprocess:false"<<endl;

    //cout<<GetLastError()<<endl; //Output the last error.

    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

Second process:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int b;

    b = GetCurrentProcessId();

    cout << b << endl;
    cout << "Druecken Sie Enter zum Beenden" << endl;
    cin.get();
        //Wait until the user confirms

    Sleep (700);
    ExitProcess(0);

    cout<<"test";
}
```

The first process prints false, false ; but it should print true, false.

Instead of the if-else statement, I used this:

```
//switch(WaitForSingleObject (pro2info.hProcess, INFINITE)){
    //    case WAIT_OBJECT_0: cout << "ja";
    //        break;
    //    case WAIT_FAILED:cout << "nein";
    //        break;
    //    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
    //        break;
    //}
//    cout<<"waitprocess:true"<<endl;//prozess ist fertig
//else
//    cout<<"waitprocess:false"<<endl;
```

And this seems to work. What did I do wrong with my `if-else` statement?

Comment: Side-note: I'm 99% certain that `CloseHandle(pro2info.hProcess);` renders `pro2info.hProcess` invalid for *all* further use; the subsequent call to `WaitForSingleObject(pro2info.hProcess, INFINITE)` is at best going to fail, and at worst wait on some random handle opened in some other thread that happened to be assigned the same numeric value after the original handle was closed. Don't call `CloseHandle` until you're *done* with the `HANDLE` for good.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You *really* need to pay attention to the meaning for the return value of the API functions.  You cannot ignore a FALSE return from CreateProcess().  WaitForSingleObject() can return several values, it returns 0 if the wait completed successfully.  Which makes you print "false".

Answer (score 5):

According to [MSDN, WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032%28VS.85%29.aspx) will return WAIT_OBJECT_0 if the wait wasn't aborted. If you check the documentation, the value of WAIT_OBJECT_0 happens to be 0x00000000L, which happens to be the value commonly converted to `false`, not `true`. Hence your comparison fails.

Promoting the return value of `WaitForSingleObject` to a `bool` is IMHO not a good idea given that you get several potentially illuminating non-zero return codes that indicate why the wait expired.

If you still want to keep the above code as using a boolean check, change the tests to `!WaitForSingleObject(...)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think you sort of answered your question yourself. The point is that `WaitForSingleObject` doesn't return `true` or `false`, but `WAIT_OBJECT_0` et al.

So instead of

```
if (retwait= WaitForSingleObject (pro2info.hProcess, INFINITE)==true)
```

you need

```
if (retwait= WaitForSingleObject (pro2info.hProcess, INFINITE)==WAIT_OBJECT_0)
```